# Help Fallback (thumbnail)

Tags: php, theme-development, shortcode, post-thumbnails

Sorry for my bad English but I give it a try.

I create a Wordpress theme with a shortcode to show the latest 3 posts in a column see this picture below

[image]

I have tried different codes too if there is no URL of the thumbnail that the fallback in a default image.

Here is the code

```
global $post;

$html = "";

$my_latest_posts_widget = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'posts_per_page' => 3
));
$html .= '<div id="container_recent_posts_widget" class="container_recent_posts_widget">';
if( $my_latest_posts_widget->have_posts() ) : while( $my_latest_posts_widget->have_posts() ) : $my_latest_posts_widget->the_post();
     $html .= '<div class="recent_posts_widget_post">';
     $html .= '<a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .' "><div><img class="attachment-blogthumbhomewidget size-blogthumbhomewidget wp-post-image" src="' .

    $thumb

      . '" alt="' .get_the_title(). ' | ' .get_bloginfo(). '"/></div></a>';
     $html .= '<a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .' "><h2 class="recent-posts-widget-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h2></a>';
     $html .= '<a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .' "><p class="recent-posts-widget-text">' . excerpt(20) . '</p></a>';
     $html .= '<div class="lees-meer-post-div"><a class="lees-meer-post-a" href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .' "><span class="lees-meer-post-widget">Lees meer</span></a></div> ';
     $html .= "</div>";
endwhile; endif;

echo '</div>';

return $html;
```

I found this code on a forum but this gives all of the posts a default thumbnail. But the post first post "Testje" has a thumbnail but it fallbacks on the default image.

Here is the code that I found on that forum

```
    $thumb = get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/default-image-post-thumbnail-widget.jpg';
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
 //override  fallback image if post has any thumbnail
 $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
  }
```

Can anyone help me to do this on the right way?

Thanks! :)

Comment: show the complete code you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
global $post;

$html = "";

$my_latest_posts_widget = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'posts_per_page' => 3
));
$html .= '<div id="container_recent_posts_widget" class="container_recent_posts_widget">';

if( $my_latest_posts_widget->have_posts() ) : while( $my_latest_posts_widget->have_posts() ) : $my_latest_posts_widget->the_post();

  $thumb = get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/default-image-post-thumbnail-widget.jpg';
  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    //override  fallback image if post has any thumbnail
    $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
  }

 $html .= '<div class="recent_posts_widget_post">';
 $html .= '<a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .' "><div><img class="attachment-blogthumbhomewidget size-blogthumbhomewidget wp-post-image" src="' .

$thumb

  . '" alt="' .get_the_title(). ' | ' .get_bloginfo(). '"/></div></a>';
 $html .= '<a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .' "><h2 class="recent-posts-widget-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h2></a>';
 $html .= '<a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .' "><p class="recent-posts-widget-text">' . excerpt(20) . '</p></a>';
 $html .= '<div class="lees-meer-post-div"><a class="lees-meer-post-a" href=" ' . get_the_permalink() .' "><span class="lees-meer-post-widget">Lees meer</span></a></div> ';
 $html .= "</div>";
endwhile; endif;

echo '</div>';

return $html;
```